# Multiple public/private keyword in class definition

Tags: c++, c++11

I have seen multiple public and private keywords in a class definition, like the example below:

```
class myClass
{
  public:
    void func1(){}
  public:
    void func2(){}
  private:
    int x;
    int y;
  private:
    int z;
    int baz;
};
```

What is the practical use of this (if any)? Is there ***any*** situation in which this could be useful?

Comment: Why do you think there's a practical use for this, aside from aesthetics? I mean you can always reorder the methods so that you only need a single keyword each

Comment: That's why I'm asking. Wasn't sure if there's some hidden reason for this that I have yet to discover...which is why I'm curiously posting the question on SO

Comment: The main reason that I've used these in the past is to separate the various concerns of my class visually. I'll set up groups, alternate between public & private members of those groups, and so on.

Comment: It's a long shot, but maybe when automatically generating code, it's more convenient to put `public:`, `private:` or `protected:` before *every* member.

Comment: You might care about the order of initialization of sub-objects.

Comment: "aesthetics" is actually a practical reason too; making your code easier to read means it's easier to maintain.

Comment: What makes you think there *isn't* a practical use for this? Why the presumption?

Comment: @EJP Being a greenhorn...I see some code written by someone I look up to, and have no idea whether it is for a very good reason, or an accident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any situation in which this could be useful?

I can think of a situation where it would be very problematic otherwise:

```
 class myClass
{
  public:
    void func1(){}
  public:
    void func2(){}
  COORDINATES;    // <-- Note the macro here!
  private:
    int z;
    int baz;
};
```

which, after the expansion of the `COORDINATES` macro, becomes:

```
class myClass
{
  public:
    void func1(){}
  public:
    void func2(){}
  private:
    int x;
    int y;
  private:
    int z;
    int baz;
};
```

If multiple `private` / `public` keywords weren't allowed, it would be very painful to do it. Although using macros isn't good practice; neither is introducing access modifiers silently for all the members appearing after the macro. Nevertheless, it could be useful for RAD tools generating C++ source code.

I can only guess why you see that in human written classes. My guess is that it is poor coding; the writer probably wanted to express that a chunk of data belongs together and / or wanted to be able to move up and down those chunks within the class definition, together with the corresponding access modifier (`private/protected/public`).

Answer (score 1):

I'll go one step farther from my comment for this answer, with a snippet of code.

```
class myClass {

    // initializers etc
    public:
        myClass();
        ~myClass();

    // signal processing
    public:
        void modifyClass();
    private:
        float signalValue;

    // other class responsibilities
    public:
        void doWork();
    private:
        void workHelper();
};
```

and so on. I wouldn't say this is a solid DESIGN for the class, but it's a good way to show the different capabilities of a class.

Comment: I am not sure I can call this solid - what's wrong with just saying: `public: // initializers etc ... // signal processing ... // other ...` followed by the same order now with `private`? That way the public interface that I care about as the reader of your code remains at the top of the class, and I don't have to hunt for it in the innards of the declaration.

Comment: Agree w/ @mockinterface: SRP (Single Responsibility) suggests that there should not be "other class responsibilities" at all, and anyway your public methods should always be at or near the top, because they are what matter to most readers.

Answer (score 1):

Another use is when you want to have a specific destruction order. Lets consider two cases:

1. Bad case

   ```
   // Auxiliary class
   Class StorageCleaner {
   public:
       StorageCleaner(ExternalStorage* storage) : storage_(storage);
       ~StorageCleaner() { storage_->DeleteEverything(); }
   private:
       ExternalStorage* const storage_;  // Not owned
   }

   // Class with bad declaration order
   Class ExternalStorageWrapper {
   public:
       ExternalStorageWrapper(ExternalStorage* storage) : cleaner_(storage) {
           pointer_to_storage_.reset(storage);
       }
       const StorageCleaner cleaner_;  
   private:
       std::unique_ptr<ExternalStorage> pointer_to_storage_;

       // Other data which should be private
       int other_int;
       string other_string;
       .... 
   };
   ```

   What happens when existing `ExternalStorageWrapper` object goes out of scope?

   - The ExternalStorageWrapper destructor will first
     destroy other data
   - Then it will destroy external storage pointed by `pointer_to_external_storage_` (because fields are destroyed in **reversed declaration order**).
   - Then it will attempt to destroy `cleaner_`
   - But cleaner inside its own destructor attempts to manipulate external storage, which has already been destroyed!
2. Good case

   ```
   // Class StorageCleaner same as before
   ...

   // Class with better declaration order
   Class ExternalStorageWrapper {
   private:
       std::unique_ptr<ExternalStorage> pointer_to_storage_;

   public:
       ExternalStorageWrapper(ExternalStorage* storage) : cleaner_(storage) {
           pointer_to_storage_.reset(storage);
       }
       const StorageCleaner cleaner_;

   private:
       // Other data which should be private
       int other_int;
       string other_string;
           .... 
   };
   ```

   What happens in this case when existing `ExternalStorageWrapper` object goes out of scope?

   - The ExternalStorageWrapper destructor will first destroy other data.
   - Then it will attempt to destroy `cleaner_`. Cleaner will `DeleteEverything()` from storage using `storage_` pointer to still existing storage.
   - Finally, storage gets destroyed through `pointer_to_storage_`.

I actually had to debug such problem in a company, so although rare, this peculiar case is possible to occur.

Answer (score 0):

One use case I encounter is for the clarity. As shown in the example below, `class1` inherits `base` class which contains a pure virtual function that `class1` needs to implement. To indicate that `method1` in `class1` is coming from some other class `class1` inherits from (e.g. `base`) instead of `class1`'s own function, we use another `public` to make this point clear:

```
class base {
public:
   virtual void method1() = 0;
}

class class1: base {
public:
   myOwnMethod1();
   myOwnMethod2();
public: /* base interface */
   method1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just finished reading those examples. Hopefully this  one could contribute on how useful multiple keyword definition is.
We don't quite need to assume much since this is my current problem as of now but consume the following:

```
class IOHandler {
public:
    enum COLOR_DEFINITIONS : unsigned char
    {
        BLACK,
        DARK_ER_BLUE,
        DARK_GREEN,
        DARK_SKY_BLUE,
        DARK_RED,
        DARK_PINK,
        DARK_YELLOW,
        DARK_WHITE,
        DARK_GREY,
        DARK_BLUE,
        BRIGHT_GREEN,
        BRIGHT_SKY_BLUE,
        BRIGHT_RED,
        BRIGHT_PINK,
        BRIGHT_YELLOW,
        BRIGHT_WHITE
    };
    template <typename dtEX>
    void showOutputEx(dtEX literalOutput, _COLOR_OUTPUT textColorSet = {COLOR_DEFINITIONS::BRIGHT_WHITE , COLOR_DEFINITIONS::BRIGHT_YELLOW}, bool appendOutputType = true, OUTPUT_TYPE levelOutput = OUTPUT_TYPE::OUTPUT_NORMAL, EMBRACE_TYPE embraceOutputType = EMBRACE_TYPE::EMBRACE_OUTPUT_LEVEL, ...);
    // !                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Doesn't detect the struct being referenced at which is at below.
private:
    typedef struct colorProps // This is the struct that the public function where trying to get referenced at but failed to do so.
    {
        unsigned char C_BG = 0,
                      C_FG = 0;
    } _COLOR_OUTPUT;
};
```

The error code.

```
identifier "_COLOR_OUTPUT" is undefined.
```

At this point, my intelliSense keep complaining that `_COLOR_OUTPUT` is undefined within public class scope.
The most probable solution is to put the struct inside public scope instead of private scope.
But I don't want to.

The reason this happens was due to the compiler reads the file from top to bottom. Anything that is declared
that requires reference should be on top and that should resolve the issue. Since I don't want to make things messed up by putting all private class functions and variables
on top. I should just declare another specifier on the top so that any public function requiring some reference might see it ahead.

So the solution is the following: (Is to move all referrable variables and struct on top of the class so that any private and public function argument reference is being recognized.)

```
class IOHandler {
// Private Class Scope for Variables and Structure
private:
    typedef struct colorProps // This is the struct we move at the top for recognizing references.
    {
        unsigned char C_BG = 0,
                      C_FG = 0;
    } _COLOR_OUTPUT;
public:
    enum COLOR_DEFINITIONS : unsigned char
    {
        BLACK,
        DARK_ER_BLUE,
        DARK_GREEN,
        DARK_SKY_BLUE,
        DARK_RED,
        DARK_PINK,
        DARK_YELLOW,
        DARK_WHITE,
        DARK_GREY,
        DARK_BLUE,
        BRIGHT_GREEN,
        BRIGHT_SKY_BLUE,
        BRIGHT_RED,
        BRIGHT_PINK,
        BRIGHT_YELLOW,
        BRIGHT_WHITE
    };
    template <typename dtEX>
    void showOutputEx(dtEX literalOutput, _COLOR_OUTPUT textColorSet = {COLOR_DEFINITIONS::BRIGHT_WHITE , COLOR_DEFINITIONS::BRIGHT_YELLOW}, bool appendOutputType = true, OUTPUT_TYPE levelOutput = OUTPUT_TYPE::OUTPUT_NORMAL, EMBRACE_TYPE embraceOutputType = EMBRACE_TYPE::EMBRACE_OUTPUT_LEVEL, ...);
    // !                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Now recognizable reference.
private:
    ... // Any other functions, excerpt.
};
```